# Was I “laying” on the bed, or was I “lying” on the bed?

Tags: lie-lay-lain-laid

Should this sentence use *laying* or *lying*?

> Last week at this time, I was **____** on Sarah’s bed.

Can someone fill in the blank for me?

Answer (score 1):

You could use *lying*. However your might prefer *recumbent* or *prone*. The first is defined by [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) as

> [**Recumbent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recumbent)   *adj.*
>
> lying down

While the second (again from Merriam-Webster Online)

> [**Prone**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prone)   *adj.*
>
> lying with the front of your body facing downward

Answer (score 1):

*Lay* means to put or set something down. *Lie* means to be or stay in a rest position. So in your case it’s *lying*.

Comment: ("After laying myself down, I will be lying down.")

Comment: @keshalam wow great example man, you should put that an example.